# Gerar componente no angular

Tags: angular-6

Quando executo o comando

```
ng generate component configure-notification/configure-notification-edit --module app
```

ele da o seguinte erro:

```
/usr/bin/ng: line 40: exec: generate: not found
```

antes eu conseguia criar normalmente...

estou utilizando linux mint, 18.3

a saída do comando ng --version

```
/usr/bin/ng: line 40: exec: --: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
```

saida do arquivo /usr/bin/ng:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) 2000 Yasuhiro Take <take@debian.org>
# Copyright (c) 1999 Fumitoshi UKAI <ukai@debian.or.jp>
# Copyright (c) 1999 Jacobo Tarrio Barreiro <jtarrio@iname.com>
# This program is covered by the GNU General Public License version 2
#

if [ -n "$NG" ]; then
  test -x /usr/bin/$NG && exec /usr/bin/$NG "$@"
fi

test -x /usr/bin/ng-cjk-canna && NG=/usr/bin/ng-cjk-canna
test -x /usr/bin/ng-cjk && NG=/usr/bin/ng-cjk
test -x /usr/bin/ng-latin && NG=/usr/bin/ng-latin

if [ -x /usr/bin/locale ]; then
  eval `locale`
fi
locale=${LC_ALL:-$LANG}

case X"$locale" in
  Xja|Xja_JP|Xja_JP.*)
    [ -x /usr/bin/ng-latin ] && NG=/usr/bin/ng-latin
    [ -x /usr/bin/ng-cjk ] && NG=/usr/bin/ng-cjk
    [ -x /usr/bin/ng-cjk-canna ] && NG=/usr/bin/ng-cjk-canna
    ;;
  Xko|Xko_KR|Xko_KR.*|Xzh|Xzh_CN|Xzh_CN.*)
    [ -x /usr/bin/ng-latin ] && NG=/usr/bin/ng-latin
    [ -x /usr/bin/ng-cjk-canna ] && NG=/usr/bin/ng-cjk-canna
    [ -x /usr/bin/ng-cjk ] && NG=/usr/bin/ng-cjk
    ;;
  *)
    [ -x /usr/bin/ng-cjk-canna ] && NG=/usr/bin/ng-cjk-canna
    [ -x /usr/bin/ng-cjk ] && NG=/usr/bin/ng-cjk
    [ -x /usr/bin/ng-latin ] && NG=/usr/bin/ng-latin
    ;;
esac

if [ -n $NG ]; then
  exec $NG "$@"
else
  echo "Neither ng-latin, ng-cjk, nor ng-cjk-canna found."
  echo "Please install what you prefer."
fi
```

Obrigada.

Comment: Esse comando é suposto mostrar uma [mensagem toda bonita](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAY7y.png) com a informação dos várias partes do core do angular. O angular cli não deve ter ficado corretamente instalado na sua maquina e convem reinstalar, quer seja globalmente ou localmente.

Answer (score 1):

**Editado**

Vendo o arquivo `/usr/bin/ng` percebesse que você sta tendo conflito de pacotes, você tem instalado na sua máquina o pacote `ng-common` recomendo que você faça o seguinte:

Desinstale o pacote ng-common e quaisquer outros pacotes dependentes, e depois faça a reinstalação do angular conforme comentei abaixo.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ng-common
```

---

**Reinstalação**

Segue comandos para desinstalar:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
```

Depois disso verifique com o comando:
   ng --version

***Se der erro, então você realmente desinstalou :)***

Depois instale novamente :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

---

**Observações :**

- Utilizando `--force` você limpa todo o cache
- Utilize **sudo** (`$ sudo <comando>`)
- Se você esta utilizando a versão do npm menor que a`5` será necessário fazer a verificação de cache. (`$ npm cache verify`)

Comment: alterei a pergunta

Comment: desinstalei e instalei novamente... e não adiantou nada

Comment: Estranho, parece que tem outro pacote que é chamado com ng instalado na sua máquina, consegue postar aqui a saída do arquivo /usr/bin/ng

Comment: atualizei a pergunta

Comment: @bruna Atualizei minha resposta, espero que agora resolva :)

Comment: @bruna Mas instalou de novo através dos repositórios ou fazendo download pela página official ? É que os repositórios do mint tem versões bem antigas de alguns softwares, dos quais um deles é o node.